why does my browser flashes results in split milliseconds on the screen when i added ".addEventListener" to the button element
Whenever i called a function to render on the console or browser to see how the codes are working, the called function, for instance a button with addEventListener in particular, the result will just flash and disappeared within a split milliseconds either it's on the browser, or when i console.log() it.
i can't really figure out why it is like that, i have change from Edge browser to chrome browser and vice versa.
and this only happen with my javascript file, specifically, when i added ".addEventListener" to button element to call a function that return values from input tag element.
since i added ".addeventListener" it started rendering the result it calls in flashes, within a blink of an eye. This happen either on the console or on the browser.
it has even after the other function passed to it, as they come in flashes within a split second. any explanation will be welcome.


const formNum = document.getElementById("formEl")
formNum.addEventListener("submit", () =>
    const userVehNum = (ownerInput) => {
        console.log(`please confirm this: ${ownerInput})`);
<input type="alphanumeric" class="inputbox" id="inputdig" placeholder="Enter your plate Number">
<button class="btn" onclick="openPopUp()">Submit</button>




it is a two part question though, the other part of the question will be how to pass function into the div. details of which will come after the above....if i make an attempt and i can resolve the issue. thank

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

I have sort out the issue, I got to understand that the script speed is faster than the DOM. The answers lie in the prevent default in my form submit button. Thanks stacks @DarkBee
